# Values of Column A to be copied in Column C if Column B value matches

Tags: excel

My question is to Find if value in column  A contains value from column B.

Basically, I have 2 columns. Column A contains URLs (7533 rows). Column B contains URL slugs (215 rows).

I want to search to see if Column B value matches with Column A, then copy the value in Column C.

Comment: you just use this in column C in front every cell with a value in column B : 
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,A:A,1,0),"Unfound")`

Comment: Clarify "then copy the value in Column C."  You haven't told us anything about column C

Comment: @Fnayou vlookup only finds exact matches.

Comment: @findwindow Indeed, that's what he has asked for, no ? _"I want to search to see if Column B value matches with Column A, then copy the value in Column C."_

Comment: `Column B contains URL slugs` suggesting it holds partial strings in column A?