# Power Query - Check if value in column B exists in column A

Tags: powerquery

I have tried this with a list of 500 rows and it works great. But when I try to add it to my real query of 500k rows it takes forever (looking at row count I see that it would take days to finish).
Is there any way to speed it up by "Buffering" or "Query List"?
I'm very new to Power Query and is using it with Excel only

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "TYPE_CHECK", each List.Contains(#"Source"[TYPE_SORT],[MASTER]))
```

[this code work great but take to much resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339257/values-of-column-a-to-be-copied-in-column-c-if-column-b-value-matches)

Example of what is expected:

[image: example of what is expected]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to see if items in column of Table2 appear in column of Table1. Another way to do it is just merge the two tables

[image]

base version:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"AAA", type text}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"AAA"}, Table2, {"BBB"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"BBB"}, {"BBB"})
in  #"Expanded Table2"
```

alternate True/False version

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"AAA", type text}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"AAA"}, Table2, {"BBB"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"BBB"}, {"BBB"}),
ConvertTrueFalse = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Table2",{{"BBB", each if _=null then false else true}})
in  ConvertTrueFalse
```

You can also merge the same table on top of itself to check columns against each other in the same table

[image]

merge table on itself:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"AAA", type text}, {"BBB", type text}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"AAA"}, #"Changed Type", {"BBB"}, "Changed Type", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Changed Type" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Changed Type", {"BBB"}, {"AAAmatchfromBBB"}),
#"MakeTrueFalse" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Changed Type",{{"AAAmatchfromBBB", each if _=null then false else true}})
in  #"MakeTrueFalse"
```

Answer (score 0):

Right before you AddColumn, you insert a standalone step

```
BufferList = List.Buffer(#"Source"[TYPE_SORT])
```

Then on the AddColumn step, you use

```
#"Added Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "TYPE_CHECK", each List.Contains(BufferList,[MASTER]))
```

Comment: I tried the BufferList with a small test Query of 8600 rows and if went from 7 minutes (422 sec) without Buffer to less than 2 sec. with. I will try it on my full scale Query which have 500k rows and see what the outcom will be. will get back to you. Thanks for support!

Comment: It should be relatively same, as long as you have enough high performance memory to cache the buffer. If that memory is not enough, then it will be slow as well. You can increase the size of cache in settings, but be careful, it could make PQ sluggish and unstable.

Comment: So here are my findings.
From my simple test file it went approx. 250 times faster with List.Buffer
In my real data which is much bigger and more complex with a total of 418k rows the difference was about 7 times quicker
That means it went from calculated assumption 280 hours to 41 hours so not that meaningful
I would need a speed increase of about 10 000 for it to make sense
The data source is from a folder with more than 30 text files
Bottom line is that I have to skip this step :(

Comment: That sounds normal, If you run out of memory, `Table.Buffer` will hurt performance a lot.